# Absolute positioning an element inside a fixed positioned div IE not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

OK, this is driving me crazy now, I already messed with all my code and still can't get this to work.

I am developing a WP theme and for it I am offering users the possibility to choose between a fixed header or a fluid one.

The problem comes when the user selects the fixed one under IE where the dropdown menu is not showing at all.

I created an example site here: http://makanudos.com/tests/ for anyone who may be willing to help me.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Which browser are you experiencing this problem on? This seems to work fine in Chrome.

Comment: I only experience the problem with IE 7/8

Comment: So you're experiencing a problem with `SlideDown()` in jQuery.

Comment: But it works when I remove the fixed property of the mother div. It just happens when I fix the header to the top and in all cases just under IE. Any clue? Thanks!

Comment: I have a solution for IE8. Sorry I don't have IE7 so cannot confirm if the same solution applies.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wow, took me a while to find this one… and it's a bug in IE8.

```
#menuConquistador { filter: alpha(opacity=96); }
```

is breaking the display in IE8. Disabling it makes the menu appear as expected.

I thought it would be as simple as setting it differently as [this article suggests](http://acidmartin.wordpress.com/2008/11/28/setting-opacity-and-other-filters-in-internet-explorer-8/), however, even using the correct IE8 `-ms-filter` extension causes the sub-menu to hide under the rest of the page.

**Edit:** You might find some workarounds [here](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/ie-position-fixed-opacity-filter) if you really need a 96% opaque menu :-) Personally, I'd just remove the filter for IE7/8. Users with decent browsers can get the nice transparent effect.

Also, just found [Internet Explorer CSS property "filter" ignores overflow:visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3619383/internet-explorer-css-property-filter-ignores-overflowvisible)

**Edit 2:** OK, so adding

```
#menuConquistador { -ms-filter: 'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=50)'; }
```

**and** removing the `z-index:10000` (there seems to be two for the `#menuConquistador` selector) allows the menu appear in IE8 and have opacity!

Comment: Go, thanks SOO MUCH @andyb! I was really frustrated with this one and you got it in 5' minutes!! Genius!